# Pandas Google Distance Matrix API - Pass coordinates into URL

Tags: python, json, google-maps, pandas, urllib

I am working with the Google Distance Matrix API, where I want to feed coordinates from a dataframe into the API and return the duration and distance between the two points. 
Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import simplejson
import urllib
import numpy as np

Record   orig_lat    orig_lng       dest_lat     dest_lng      
1        40.7484405  -74.0073127    40.7115242   -74.0145492   
2        40.7421218  -73.9878531    40.7727216   -73.9863531
```

First, I need to combine the **orig_lat** & **orig_lng** and **dest_lat** & **dest_lng** into strings, which then pass into the url. So I've tried creating the variables **orig_coord** & **dest_coord** then passing them into the URL and returning values:

```
orig_coord = df[['orig_lat','orig_lng']].apply(lambda x: '{},{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
dest_coord = df[['dest_lat','dest_lng']].apply(lambda x: '{},{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)

for row in df.itertuples():
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&units=imperial&MYGOOGLEAPIKEY".format(orig_coord,end_coord)
    result = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    df['driving_time_text'] = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']
```

But I get the following error: "TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"

So my question is: how do I concatenate values from two columns into a string, then pass that string into a URL and output the result?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I am not sure how you constructed your data frame. Maybe post those details? But if you can live with referencing tuple elements positionally, this worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'orig_lat': 40.748441, 'orig_lng': -74.007313, 'dest_lat': 40.711524, 'dest_lng': -74.014549}, 
        {'orig_lat': 40.742122, 'orig_lng': -73.987853, 'dest_lat': 40.772722, 'dest_lng': -73.986353}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for row in df.itertuples():
 orig_coord='{},{}'.format(row[1],row[2])
 dest_coord='{},{}'.format(row[3],row[4])
 url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&units=imperial&MYGOOGLEAPIKEY".format(orig_coord,dest_coord)
 print url
```

produces

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=40.748441,-74.007313&destinations=40.711524,-74.014549&units=imperial&MYGOOGLEAPIKEY
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=40.742122,-73.987853&destinations=40.772722,-73.986353&units=imperial&MYGOOGLEAPIKEY
```

To update the data frame with the result, since `row` is a tuple and not writeable, you might want to keep track of the current index as you iterate. Maybe something like this:

```
data = [{'orig_lat': 40.748441, 'orig_lng': -74.007313, 'dest_lat': 40.711524, 'dest_lng': -74.014549, 'result': -1}, 
        {'orig_lat': 40.742122, 'orig_lng': -73.987853, 'dest_lat': 40.772722, 'dest_lng': -73.986353, 'result': -1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
i_row = 0
for row in df.itertuples():
 orig_coord='{},{}'.format(row[1],row[2])
 dest_coord='{},{}'.format(row[3],row[4])
 url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&units=imperial&MYGOOGLEAPIKEY".format(orig_coord,dest_coord)
 # Do stuff to get your result
 df['result'][i_row] = result
 i_row++
```

Comment: I edited it to show one way to update the data frame... but there are certainly other ways to do it.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the help. This still wasn't able to work for me. I think it has something to do with the i_row. Do you have any other ideas? I've been searching around and can't find much.

Comment: I forgot one line, `i_row++` ... does that help?

Comment: That didn't quite work, but I was able to find a workaround by creating a list and using list.append(result). I doubt if this is the most efficient way, but it works for this purpose. Thank's again Mike!

Comment: I should have said `i += 1`, not `i++` -- python does not have the `++` and `--` increment and decrement operators. Glad you found a working solution!